# Does it make any difference if I add brackets in the LHS while assigning multiple variables at once? If so, how? and why?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, naming-conventions, variable-assignment

If I add brackets (like [a,b] or (a,b) ) enclosing the varibles in the LHS, will it make any difference in the type of variables stored or any other difference, whatsoever?

Ex:

```
a,b=1,2
(a,b)=1,2
[a,b]=1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you've given there, it doesn't make any difference. However, if there are nested sequences on the right hand side of the expression, you need to use matching brackets on the left-hand-side to avoid a `ValueError`:

```
>>> a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
>>> a, b, c = 1, (2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
>>> a, (b, c) = 1, (2, 3)
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
>>> a, (b, c) = 1, ((2,), (3,))
>>> a, b, c
(1, (2,), (3,))
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(b)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> a, ((b,), (c,)) = 1, ((2,), (3,))
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
```